# How do I change hostname?

Tags: bash, hostname, prompt

The hostname of my name is very long, which is odd. How can change the hostname for my system?

My hostname, currently, is

`himanshu@himanshu-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~$`

Is there any way I can shorten this or change it entirely?

Comment: First, check the linked question and, second, if this is a clean installation, a simple fix would be to just reinstall it and change the hostname that is filled in after you enter your name while Ubuntu is installing. As for an easier fix, I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and enter this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hostname
```

Enter your password, and then a file will open. Just change the name to the new hostname, and save the file. Do the same with the hosts file, by running:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts
```

Edit the name to your new hostname after 127.0.0.1 and save.

Restart your computer, and it should be done.

Edit: Use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. It's safer.

Comment: At all `sudo gedit` or `sudo <any GUY application>` is not a good idea. This will change the ownership of some files and folder within your home directory, that will cause future errors. To recover from this problem you should run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME`. For future use `sudo -i gedit`, or `sudo -H gedit`, or better `sudo nano filename`.

Comment: sudo -e filename

Comment: @pa4080  I did not have knowledge of that. Learned something new. Thank You.

Comment: Use `gksudo` it  is much safer than `sudo` Ex : `gksudo gedit filename`